# How to print the elements of a double float array using a pointer variable

Tags: c, pointers

The multiline comments are the print for loops that don't work. Otherwise the function runs fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double inner_product(const double *a, const double *b, int n);

int main(void){
  int n, p;
  double *e, y[n],z[n];
  
  printf("Key in the length of array:\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  /* Loop that takes a value and stores is in an array position */
  printf("Key in the first array: \n");
  for(p = 0; p < n; p++){
    scanf("%lf", &y[p]);
  }

  /*
  printf("Your first array is: ");
  for(e = &y[0]; e < &y[n]; e++){
    printf(" %lf, \n", *e);
  }
  */
  


  printf("\n");

  printf("Key in the second array: \n");
  for(p = 0; p < n; p++){
    scanf("%lf", &z[p]);
  }

  /*
  printf("Your second array is: \n");
  for(e = y; e < y + n; e++){
    printf("%lf, \n", *e);
  }
  */

  printf("\n");
  
  printf("The Inner product is: %lf \n", inner_product(y,z,n));

  return 0;
}


double inner_product(const double *a, const double *b, int len){
  const double *pointera, *pointerb;
  double sum;
  for(pointera = a, pointerb = b; pointera < a + len && pointerb < a + len; pointera++, pointerb++){
    sum += *pointera * *pointerb;
    printf("The sum of the current position is %lf and the current sum is %lf\n", *pointera * *pointerb, sum);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

The segment commented out is the problem, the code works perfectly without the print section but I don't know how to print a double array with a pointer, only a integer array. I tried to use a float in place of n on the second array print but it brought up an error.

Comment: You define the arrays `y` and `z` *before* you have initialized `n`, which `n` have an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: `&& pointerb < a + len;` in the function is wrong...

Comment: `double sum;` is uninitialised... Lucky you aren't getting NAN or some other complete failure.

Comment: What does your textbook say about it?

Comment: _"brought up an error"_: which error. Show the verbatim error log.

Comment: [How to declare variable-length arrays correctly?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283440)